# ORA-00997: Illegal use of LONG datatype Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm getting the error below while trying to convert the datatype of the LONG value to char

select  DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(a.sql_statement_text)
from alr_alerts a,alr_actions aa
where a.alert_id = aa.alert_id
and a.alert_id =100081

[image]

`sql_statement_text` is defined as a LONG column.

Comment: The `long` data type is deprecated [and has many restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F6309DF8-162F-48A4-9454-FEE59EC6644F). Your life will be easier if you can make the column a CLOB instead. You've tagged this as PL/SQL but only shown SQL; if you are using PL/SQL you can use a long variable to work around some limitations and convert to CLOB locally. (Also, please don't post images; use formatted text.)

Comment: As a workaround for SQL - use `dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype` to serialize result to XML and then `xmltable` to deserialize it back as a `clob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `long` cannot be used in SQL functions, so you'd better redesign table's structure and convert it to `clob` to make life easier.

But if you still need to access this data having `long` as a source type, you may use two approaches.

- Local function declaration that will fetch `long` (in PL/SQL) and convert it to `clob`. This is available since 12.1, but it will open a new child cursor per row.

> ```
> with function f_get_long_as_clob(
>   p_id int
> ) return clob
> as
>   l_long long;
> begin
>   select do_not_use_long
>     into l_long
>   from test_tab
>   where id = p_id;
>
>   return to_clob(l_long);
> end;
>
> select
>   test_tab.id,
>   f_get_long_as_clob(id) as clob_val
> from test_tab
> where id < 3
> ```

- Serialization of `long` to XML and subsequent deserialization as `clob`.

> ```
> select *
> from xmltable(
>   '/ROWSET/ROW'
>   passing dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select * from test_tab where id < 3')
>   columns
>     id int,
>     clob_val clob path 'DO_NOT_USE_LONG'
> )
> ```

For this sample data:

```
create table test_tab (
  id int,
  do_not_use_long long
);

insert into test_tab
select level, lpad(level, 10, '0')
from dual
connect by level < 3;
```

both solutions will return

| ID | CLOB_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0000000001 |
| 2 | 0000000002 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bkfC-CEI)